# When Image is taken from camera Intent is always landscape

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation, android-camera-intent

Hi guys I am building an application in which I want the user to take an image from camera and set it as a profile pic. The image is taken fine and saved but is always in LANDSCAPE. I want it to be in the correct orientation.

Before this post is flagged duplicate I have to say that I already tried multiple answer I searched in similar questions. The only one succeeded is the following. But when it close the app and reopen it the orientation resets.

My code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

                try {
                    bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);
                    fixOrientation();
                    imagePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.waiterPhoto);
                    imagePhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    Toast.makeText(UserData.this, "Image has been saved to " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " as " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editor.putString(fileName, uri.toString());
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                }
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(UserData.this, "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

My `fixOrientationMethod()`:

```
public void fixOrientation() {
        if (bmp.getWidth() > bmp.getHeight()) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp , 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }
    }
```

My `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_data);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        imagePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.waiterPhoto);
        String commited = sharedPreferences.getString(fileName, null);
        if(commited != null) {
            imagePhoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse(commited));
        }



        imagePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                //values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                //uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "waiterProfile.jpg");
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                //uri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

in Your `onCreate()`

```
imagePhoto.setRotation(90);
```

In your `activityResult()`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                taken = true;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                try {
                    bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);

                    imagePhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    imagePhoto.setRotation(90);
                    Toast.makeText(UserData.this, "Image has been saved to " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " as " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    editor.putString(fileName, uri.toString());
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                taken = false;
                Toast.makeText(UserData.this, "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

It will work but i dont know if it will for every device!!!